# Reasons for not building a website in images

Tags: html

I am planing to build websites like in the old 90s. The pages will consist of one big background image like in the example below. I know the following:

- Google won't be able to index any content
- If some one will zoom in on the page it will not look good
- The image will be cached wich might lead to some update-problems

Am I missing some important "knowing" above?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Background image</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0;background:url(one-fat-background.jpg) center top;height:4593px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
In here I might absolute position some content.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't forget <frameset>s for that good old 90s feeling *shudders*

Comment: You definitly wouldn't want to build it without html5.

Comment: A "big" background image might slow down loading during first visit.

Comment: Google will indeed index your content, even your images, this isn't the reason not to use images, it's more of a usability reason and page speed really.

Comment: I don't remember whole webpages being implemented as single images. Given the bandwidth in the 90s, that would have been a terrible strain on my modem. Many did use graphics for header texts though, where we now use `@font-face`. This because we didn't have as many fonts installed on our machines as we do now.

Comment: @Filburt: Well, OP is obviously aware that it won't be indexed, so (s)he might need the thing for completely different reasons.

Comment: It's a waste of bandwidth and results in a slower experience for the end user and hurts mobile users' data quotas. It harms user experience by removing features like copy & paste and machine translation. It makes you look like a terrible designer, developer, and possibly person.

Comment: @Jordan: oh come on. A terrible person?! LOL

Comment: @MrLister: The root page at apple.com was built this way and several other companies did this too. The images used to be sliced in multipe small pieces to load faster (in parallel). It allowed for a pixel perfect presentation at the expense of usability.

Comment: @Groo Apparently these reasons are beyond the scope of this question so the html5 tag not really usefull. The whole post smells like "Rub it in on the guy on my team who proposed this solution".

Comment: Thanks for all comments! "Slow on page load" was a good point.

Answer (score 3):

If the reasons you list aren't enough (and they should be!), you missed arguably the biggest one: accessibility. Please [read up on it](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) before going ahead with this abomination...

Edit: If you find the above link a bit hard to read, the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) has a good summary at the top before getting into the details.

Comment: Thanks for sending me the link. It was quite a bit of information tough. Would you like to summarize the "accessibility problem" with using images?

Comment: @user1087110 Off the top of my head, vision-impaired users use screen readers to get information from your web site. A screen reader cannot read text that's part of an image. Also users with impaired motor function may use means of navigation (i.e. not a mouse; e.g. choosing links by typing the first few letters of the link text) that such a design could hamper.

Comment: @Jordan: Thanks for that. user1087110: What Jordan said. ;-) As an afterthought, I take it you've considered and discarded the idea of simply using a background image...? There's nothing wrong with that (well, depending on the image of course...), you'd have your image and you could still put text on top of it (again, for the sake of accessibility, make sure you have good contrast between background and text colours).

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you missed is when people turn off images, they will simply see nothing. Not even an alt text.

By the way, they didn't have HTML5 in the 90s. If you want to go 90s, go all the way and use HTML without any DOCTYPE declaration! And preferably without CSS.

But as always, the question is why? You say "websites", so I assume it won't be a single website for curiosity purposes (which I could understand). You'll be building more than one?

Comment: We are planing to build a few simple presentation websites like this. The websites will have lots of illustration work. The big background will allmoast function like sprites.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're dealing with an image that big, you might have bandwidth concerns, but I suppose that's no different from any site with a background just used for decoration. And like any site with a decoration background, you risk it not being *big enough* for larger monitors. It's very difficult to have any sort of fluid-width setup.

If you want to position content at some specific place *over* the background, you may encounter CSS issues, especially relating to cross-browser (and mobile) compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

What about maintanability? It's much harder to maintain content in Photoshop, than using a text editor.

Comment: But the designer without any html knowledge would have full control over the design (and they would probebly thik it's easier to mantain the page in photoshop)...